# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two Scala codes - MyMain.scala and MyFunction.scala, built separately and built jar of MyFunction will act as UDF in MyMain.

MyFunction.scala basically contains a Java class with a public method `public String myFunc(String val0, String val1)`. The project is built in SBT and build_jar compile output is stored as artifact (only the required class i.e. MyFunction.class, not the dependencies).

MyMain.scala imports the above artifact jar into lib folder under  and is added into the classpath using `unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"` in  `build.sbt`

So MyMain.scala project structure is as follows:

```
MyMain
| 
-lib/MyFunction.jar
       |
       - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
       - MyFunction.class
-project
-src/main/scala/MyMain.scala
-build.sbt
```

/*What I need to do*/

I want to define a UDF in MyMain.scala on the MyFunction.class within the MyFunction.jar which is added to the lib classpath. I have defined the UDF but when I am trying to use it on a Spark dataframe inside MyMain.scala, it is throwing "Task not serializable" java.io.NotSerializableException as below:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:616)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:747)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:724)
  at MyMain$.main(<pastie>:253)
  ... 58 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MyMain$
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: MyMain$, value: MyMain$@11f25cf)
    - field (class: $iw, name: MyMain$module, type: class MyMain$)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@540705e8)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@7e6e1038)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@7587f2a0)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5e00f263)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@3fbfe419)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5172e87b)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5ec96f75)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@26f6de78)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@18c3bc83)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@35d674ee)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5712092f)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@6980c2e6)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@6ce299e)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@406b8acb)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@73d71e61)
    - field (class: $line47.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line47.$read, $line47.$read@72ee2f87)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line47$read, type: class $line47.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@22c4de5a)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@3daea539)
    - field (class: $anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $anonfun$1, <function2>)
    - element of array (index: 9)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 15)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11, <function2>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
  ... 92 more
```

/*What can be the reason*/

MyMain.scala is referring to some non-serializable instance of class inside some transformation on the Spark dataframe

/*What I tried*/

```
object MyFunction extends Serializable {
  val myFuncSingleton = new MyFunction()
  def getMyFunc(var0:String,var1:String) : String = {
    myFuncSingleton.myFunc(var0,var1)
  }
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myUDF = udf((val0: String, val1: String) => { MyFunction.getMyFunc(val0, val1) })

object MyMain {
  val spark = ...
  val hadoopfs = ...
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val df1 = ...
    val df2 = df1.withColumn("reg_id", myUDF(lit("Subscriber"), col("id")))
  }
}
```

Referred to below links
[how-to-solve-non-serializable-errors-when-instantiating-objects-in-spark-udfs](https://www.placeiq.com/2017/11/how-to-solve-non-serializable-errors-when-instantiating-objects-in-spark-udfs/)

Comment: have you marked `MyFunction` class also `Serializable` ?

Comment: Yes, since Java class, `public class MyFunction implements java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did minor tweak to the code and it resolved my issue.

Though I don't fully understand the internal workings of the Scala compiler and how it handles UDF's, I will try explain my solution and what could have been the possible reason for `Task not serializable` error:

1. The use of `myUDF` variable within `withColumn(...)` is not inside any RDD closure.
2. Inside the `udf(...)` definition outside the driver program, calling of `getMyFunc(...)` on the Scala object MyFunction is equivalent of calling a static method and hence MyFunction object does not need to be serialized, as it is used as singleton object and not as an instance of `MyFunction` class (defined inside MyFunction.jar). This explains the change of `MyFunction` definition from `object MyFunction extends Serializable` to `object MyFunction`.
3. However, inside the "wrapper" singleton MyFunction object, `myFuncSingleton` is defined as an instance of `MyFunction` class (in jar) and `myFuncSingleton.myFunc(...)` calls the `myFunc(...)` method of this instance.
4. However, the `myFuncSingleton` instance and it's MyFunction class being referenced in driver program through `myUDF` is outside the RDD closure (as mentioned in 1.) and hence the MyFunction class needs to be explicitly serialized i.e. `public class MyFunction implements java.io.Serializable` (since jar built-on Java class)
5. As mentioned in 1., since UDF call within `withColumn(...)` is not within RDD closure, MyMain object needs to be serialized to make the UDF available across partitions i.e. `object MyMain extends Serializable`

   ```
   object MyFunction {
     val myFuncSingleton = new MyFunction()
     def getMyFunc(var0:String,var1:String) : String = {
       myFuncSingleton.myFunc(var0,var1)
     }
   }

   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
   val myUDF = udf((val0: String, val1: String) => { MyFunction.getMyFunc(val0, val1) })

   object MyMain extends Serializable {
     val spark = ...
     val hadoopfs = ...
     def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
       val df1 = ...
       val df2 = df1.withColumn("reg_id", myUDF(lit("Subscriber"), col("id")))
     }
   }
   ```

Note:

- To sum up, I am calling a MyFunction instance method through static method call of MyFunction singleton object. Hence, `val myFuncVar = new MyFunction()` should have been more appropriate than `val myFuncSingleton = new MyFunction()`.
- I don't fully understand the nuances of RDD closure and not sure whether withColumn() is outside the RDD closure, but assumed for sake of explanation.

Got some very good explanation here: [How Spark handles object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596871/how-spark-handles-object)