# How to call FileSystem from udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

## What I expected

The goal is to add a column with modification time to each `DataFrame` row.

Given

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("path").withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())

+----+------------------------+
| id |        input_file_name |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | hdfs://path/part-00001 |
|  2 | hdfs://path/part-00001 |
|  3 | hdfs://path/part-00002 |
+----+------------------------+
```

Expected

```
+----+------------------------+
| id |      modification_time |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01Z00:00+00:00 |
|  2 | 2000-01-01Z00:00+00:00 |
|  3 | 2000-01-02Z00:00+00:00 |
+----+------------------------+
```

## What I tried

I wrote a function to get the modification time

```scala
def getModificationTime(path: String): Long = {
    FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
        .getFileStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))
        .getModificationTime()
}

val modificationTime = getModificationTime("hdfs://srsdev/projects/khajiit/data/OfdCheques2/date=2020.02.01/part-00002-04b9e4c8-5916-4bb2-b9ff-757f843a0142.c000.snappy.parquet")
```

> modificationTime: Long = 1580708401253

... but it does not work in query

```
def input_file_modification_time = udf((path: String) => getModificationTime(path))

data.select(input_file_modification_time($"input_file_name") as "modification_time").show(20, false)
```

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 54.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 54.0 (TID 408, srs-hdp-s1.dev.kontur.ru, executor 3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$input_file_modification_time$1: (string) => bigint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `spark` is null in the UDF, because it only exists on the driver. Another problem is that hadoops `Configuration` is not serializable, so you cannot easily enclose it the the udf. But there is a workound using `org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable`:

```
import org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val conf = new SerializableWritable(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

def getModificationTime(path: String, conf:SerializableWritable[Configuration]): Long = {
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf.value)
        .getFileStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))
        .getModificationTime()
}

def input_file_modification_time(conf:SerializableWritable[Configuration]) = udf((path: String) => getModificationTime(path,conf))

data.select(input_file_modification_time(conf)($"input_file_name") as "modification_time").show(20, false)
```

Comment: getting `unread block data` errors using Spark 3.3.0 with this method.

Answer (score 1):

`Note` Invoking `getModificationTime` for each row of your DataFrame will have performance impact.

Modified your code to fetch file metadata one time & stored in `files:Map[String,Long]`, created UDF `input_file_modification_time` to fetch data from Map[String,Long].

Please check the below code.

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("/tmp/par")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int]

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def getModificationTime(path: String): Long = {
    FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
        .getFileStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))
        .getModificationTime()
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

getModificationTime: (path: String)Long

scala> implicit val files = df.inputFiles.flatMap(name => Map(name -> getModificationTime(name))).toMap
files: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(file:///tmp/par/part-00000-c6360540-c56d-48c4-8795-05a9c0ac4d18-c000_2.snappy.parquet -> 1588080295000, file:///tmp/par/part-00000-c6360540-c56d-48c4-8795-05a9c0ac4d18-c000_3.snappy.parquet -> 1588080299000, file:///tmp/par/part-00000-c6360540-c56d-48c4-8795-05a9c0ac4d18-c000_4.snappy.parquet -> 1588080302000, file:///tmp/par/part-00000-c6360540-c56d-48c4-8795-05a9c0ac4d18-c000.snappy.parquet -> 1588071322000)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def getTime(fileName:String)(implicit files: Map[String,Long]): Long = {
 files.getOrElse(fileName,0L)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

getTime: (fileName: String)(implicit files: Map[String,Long])Long

scala> val input_file_modification_time = udf(getTime _)
input_file_modification_time: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,LongType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.withColumn("createdDate",input_file_modification_time(input_file_name)).show
+---+-------------+
| id|  createdDate|
+---+-------------+
|  1|1588080295000|
|  2|1588080295000|
|  3|1588080295000|
|  4|1588080295000|
|  5|1588080295000|
|  6|1588080295000|
|  7|1588080295000|
|  8|1588080295000|
|  9|1588080295000|
| 10|1588080295000|
| 11|1588080295000|
| 12|1588080295000|
| 13|1588080295000|
| 14|1588080295000|
| 15|1588080295000|
| 16|1588080295000|
| 17|1588080295000|
| 18|1588080295000|
| 19|1588080295000|
| 20|1588080295000|
+---+-------------+
only showing top 20 rows


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It’s very cool that you also supplemented the answer by analyzing the solution in terms of performance

Answer (score 1):

all you need is some path on the system (s3://)

```
  val pathOnTheSystem = "s3://some_path"

  val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
  val uri = new URI(pathOnTheSystem)

  val fs = FileSystem.get(uri, hadoopConf)
```